# Filtering spam invitation emails

Tags: email, disreputable-publishers, spam

Is there a readily compiled, contiunously updated list of email addresse and/or domain names used in spam messages from predatory journals or conferences, or phrases or keywords that could be used to safely filter out such spam messages in email clients (without removing non-spam emails)?

Comment: I don't know of any, but I made one for myself to filter out 'To Dr My Name' as I'm not a doctor!

Comment: @Eppicurt that could cause problems, at least in my experience. Especially if you communicate with salespersons they often just add the Dr. just to be sure. And you might want to read those mails.

Comment: I would expect this list would expand so quickly and would have to be updated so often (every hour?!), that you can just as good not use it. I tend to remove everything that says "Dr. Researcher", "Dr. M Mark", "Dr. orcidid://...", "Journal of [what the f.. is that?]", "Journal of [xxx and] Research". I find spam emails are fairly easy to recognize without reading more than two words.

Comment: @Eppicurt I second DVSA's point. As a researcher without a PhD I have received plenty of legitimate email addressing me as Dr. It may be assumed or used by default for fear of offending those who have doctorates.

Comment: I keep them in a separate folder, which I check, so no nothing goes astray for me. Work colleagues and I like to share them around and make fun of them, especially when they claim I'm an 'eminent researcher in a field' of which I do not work in.

Answer (score 1):

Definitively identifying spam is next-to-impossible because:

- Spammers can change their email addresses with trivial effort.
- Spammers work hard to mimic legitimate content.
- Any spam detection method that becomes popular will be analysed and actively subverted by spammers.

All of the above are true of predatory journal spam. So I don't think there is anything like the resource you suggested (I did do a bit of searching).

Comment: It's true that it's next-to-impossible to eliminate _all_ spam, because motivated spammers will find a way. But a LOT of the "academic" spam I get is from spammers who are pretty easy to filter out, and don't seem to make much of an effort to avoid being filtered.